# std::function as method parameter

Tags: c++, stl

I'm very new to functors, and I have to create, for an API, a method which uses a function as parameter.
So, in my header, I've done:

```
typedef void(*target_function)(std::string client_ip);
void my_method(std::string path_name, std::function<target_function> a_function);
```

In my cpp, I've tried this way:

```
void my_class:: my_method(std::string path_name, std::function<target_function> )
{
    ///
}
```

but it won't compile.

I'm very confused with that... Could you please help me with that ?

EDIT:
It woks !
Thanks, all of you, for the very quick answer !

Comment: You should show the errors that are being given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Cheers-and-hth-alf is right. But I'd rather prefer this:

```
typedef std::function<void (std::string)> TTargetFunc;
void my_method(std::string path_name, TTargetFunc a_function);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try just

```
typedef void target_function(std::string client_ip);
```

Because `std::function` takes a function type as template argument, not a function pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

First drop the space and add the function name parameter name like so:

```
void my_class::my_method(std::string path_name, std::function<target_function> a_function) 
{
    /// 
}
```

Additionally you should just declare it as `std::function<void(std::string)>`. The typedef is clutter (imo).

Comment: That does not solve anything. It's totally fine to have an unnamed argument. It's silly, but it won't solve his compiler errors.

Comment: When I answered he didn't have any errors listed.  I was hazarding a guess as to what his issue was. I was right it seems about the `std::function<void(std::string)>' though.  I still think the typedef is clutter.